# How to Delete message from inbox if first word of message is 'Location'

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I would like to delete **SMS** from any number if it starts from word **LOCATION**. I am receving **Lat-Long** from client in **SMS** and show his Location on map.But i want to delete client message if his message start from word **Location**

Message Format

> Location,Lat,Long

Method to receive SMS

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.v("SMSReceiver: onReceive()" + intent);
        SharedPreferences prefs=context.getSharedPreferences("smsReceiver", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String phone="";
//        Gson gson = new Gson();
//        String json = prefs.getString("myObject", "");
//        DatabaseHandler db = gson.fromJson(json, DatabaseHandler.class);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

        Cursor cursor = db.showAllData();
        Cursor temp = cursor;
//        geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.GERMAN);

        SmsMessage[] arr = SmsPopupUtils.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
        if (arr != null) {
            for (SmsMessage sms : arr) {
                Log.v("number" + sms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                cursor = temp;
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    phone = cursor.getString(0);
                    android.util.Log.d("Excepition", phone);
                    if (sms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress().equals(phone)) {
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

                        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.smspopup_icon);
                        String data = getAddress(sms.getDisplayMessageBody());
                        mBuilder.setContentTitle("SMS Received From " + cursor.getString(1));
                        mBuilder.setContentText(data);

                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Location.class);
                        resultIntent.putExtra("phone", sms.getDisplayMessageBody());

                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
                        mNotificationManager.notify(111112, mBuilder.build());
                    }
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

        }
    }
```

Code to get **Lat-Long** and **Location** from message

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        String stringFull = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phone");
            String[] both = stringFull.split(",");
            String location=both[0];
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(both[1]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(both[2]);

         if(location.equals("Location")
              {

            /*

                Code here to delete message if first word is location... 

             */
               }
   }
```

Comment: Before you get too far into this, you should know that, since KitKat, your app cannot delete messages and cannot prevent them from being saved unless it is the default SMS app.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i know that only default SMS app is able to delete message.

Comment: OK. How do you mean to do this, exactly? Do you want to delete each message as it arrives, or just occasionally delete every message in the database that starts with "LOCATION"? The message might not be saved yet when your Receiver gets it, or when your `Activity` starts.

Comment: When new message arrives if the first word of the message is "location" than  delete the message

Comment: Well, if you have write access to the Provider, it should be something like `getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), "body LIKE ?", new String[] {"LOCATION%"});`. That should delete _every_ message in the inbox that starts with "LOCATION", no matter who it's from.

Comment: Can you please give me the full code or edit my code

Comment: Well, that's it. That's the full code. I just noticed that you edited your comment, though. If you want to delete just a single message, as it arrives, that's going to be a lot more involved, 'cause there's no guarantee it's going to be saved by the time your `Activity` starts.  You can try it out. Just put that above code in your `if(location.equals("Location"))`. Make sure your "Location" strings all match, or use `equalsIgnoreCase()`.